# Json creation taking a time

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am using SQL Server 2016

I have below query which uses View - VW_Merchant

select * from VW_Merchant takes 1 seconds to load all the records which are nearly 18k

I wanted to create my customized json out of records from that view.
I created below query -

In below query there is tag called :- PayerName which is array in json

```
DECLARE  @Merch_Uid AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ='SOMEUID'
SELECT DISTINCT MerchId, DisplayOrder, TimeStamp ,MerchName,
(
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(PayerName,'') PayerName FROM
VW_Merchant WHERE
Merch_Uid=@Merch_Uid AND
MerchId = M.MerchId 
FOR Json PATH ) AS PayerName

FROM VW_Merchant M
WHERE Merch_Uid=@Merch_Uid
```

Above query gives me perfect set of records, but the only problem is it is taking 15 seconds to load the json.

If I remove PayerName tag , it will reduce it to 5 seconds.

What changes I can make to run the query faster with PayerName tag ?

Comment: Ho can I put that in join since , there are multiple PayerName and has to accomodate in json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
DECLARE  @Merch_Uid AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ='SOMEUID'
SELECT DISTINCT MerchId, DisplayOrder, TimeStamp, MerchName,
       (SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(m2.PayerName, '') as PayerName
        FROM VW_Merchant m2
        WHERE m2.Merch_Uid = @Merch_Uid AND
              m2.MerchId = M.MerchId 
        FOR Json PATH
       ) AS PayerName
FROM VW_Merchant M
WHERE m.Merch_Uid = @Merch_Uid;
```

I would rewrite this as:

```
SELECT MerchId, DisplayOrder, TimeStamp, MerchName,
       (SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(m2.PayerName, '') as PayerName
        FROM VW_Merchant m2
        WHERE m2.Merch_Uid = @Merch_Uid AND
              m2.MerchId = M.MerchId 
        FOR Json PATH
       ) AS PayerName
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MerchId, DisplayOrder, TimeStamp, MerchName
      FROM VW_Merchant M
      WHERE m.Merch_Uid = @Merch_Uid;
     ) M;
```

Then, I would be sure the view has indexes to take advantage of the `WHERE` filtering.  Optimizing the view may be the best bet for performance.

If you were using SQL Server 2017, I would suggest a work-around using `string_agg()`.